# Error with binary storage tree fstream

Tags: c++, error-handling, tree, storage, binary-tree

I'm currently have a project were I run thorugh a text file with thousands of names and place them into a binary storage tree. Hit a stumbling block with this error:

```
error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\fstream  1116
```

I hope someone can help me explain the root problem.

thanks in advance.

josh

edit:

```
BinaryTreeStorage::BinaryTreeStorage(void) : root(NULL)
{

}

BinaryTreeStorage::~BinaryTreeStorage(void)
{

}

void BinaryTreeStorage::insert(string &input, TreeNode *&root)
{
if(root != NULL)
{
    root -> name = input;
    root -> left = NULL;
    root -> right = NULL;
}

else if (input < root -> name)
{
    insert(input, root -> left);
}
else
{
    insert(input, root -> left);
}   
}

string BinaryTreeStorage:: writeToTree(TreeNode *&root)
{
if(root ->left != NULL)
{
    writeToTree(root ->left);
}
return root->name;
if (root->right != NULL)
{
    writeToTree(root);
}
}

void BinaryTreeStorage::write(ofstream nameOut)
{
cout << "Writing out bst names" << endl;
writeToTree(root);
}

void BinaryTreeStorage::read(ifstream& nameIn)
{
cout<< "Reading in bst" << endl;
string name;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNames; i++)
{
    nameIn >> name;
    insert (name, root);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `write` function: You cannot copy an `ofstream`. Pass it by reference. Then again, you never seem to *use* the `nameOut` function argument in the body, so why not just omit it altogether:

```
void BinaryTreeStorage::write()
{
    cout << "Writing out bst names" << endl;
    writeToTree(root);
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, thankyou. The only problem is in my main now as the call needs a parameter.

    binaryTreeStorage1.write(out8);

Comment: @Josh: Well, remove it from there, too! Or pass a `std::ofstream&` to the function.

Comment: Its an assignment and we are not allowed to change the main method class unfortunatly. think i know what to do now, thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, another underhanded turns-out-to-be-homework question. *Please* tag your question as "homework" if it is thus; this is amply explained on the site FAQ.

Comment: Ah right sorry about that. I will in the future. I realise it is important that I do it myself thats why I didnt ask too much into it and more of a general idea.